# Automatically change TreeView's selection when adding a node to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a TreeView with a ContextMenu that contains options to add/remove nodes.  When I add a node to the tree, I am currently sending a command to my view model which handles the add request by adding a wrapper for the display tree and a backing data object.  When I do this, I want the newly created wrapper in the display tree to become the selected item of the treeview.  How can I do this?  I don't know how to access the treeview from the viewmodel and suspect that you might not even be supposed to.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you add a node to the tree? From View or from ViewModel?

Comment: I do it from the ViewModel.  The view passes a command parameter to a relay command, which handles the creation and removal of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel for TreeViewItem, You have an "IsSelected" Property, like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class for all ViewModel classes displayed by TreeViewItems.  
/// This acts as an adapter between a raw data object and a TreeViewItem.
/// </summary>
public class TreeViewItemViewModel : CoreViewModel
{
    #region Data

    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> _children;
    private readonly TreeViewItemViewModel _parent;

    private bool _isExpanded = false;
    private bool _isSelected;

    #endregion // Data

    #region Constructors
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region Children

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the logical child items of this object.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    #endregion // Children

    #region HasLoadedChildren
    #endregion // HasLoadedChildren

    #region IsExpanded

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
    /// associated with this object is expanded.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isExpanded)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }

            // Expand all the way up to the root.
            if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                _parent.IsExpanded = true;

            // Lazy load the child items, if necessary.
            if (this.HasDummyChild)
            {
                this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
                this.LoadChildren();
            }

        }
    }

    #endregion // IsExpanded

    #region IsSelected

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
    /// associated with this object is selected.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion // IsSelected
```

Then in your XAML, you need set up a style for TreeViewItem:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Now you can set TreeView's SelectedItem by setting IsSelected Property to True in your new added item.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you you need to bind to your SelectedItem.
So in your ViewModel create:

```
private your_object_name _selectedItem;
public your_object_name SelectedItem 
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

And in your XAML code in TreeView control:

```
 <TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

`Mode=TwoWay` allows you to change the Selection on the TreeView control using `SelectedItem` Property from you ViewModel.

Best regards.

Comment: It appears as if SelectedItem is a read-only property on TreeViews, and that I will have to make a custom TreeView control in order to do this.